# How to remove a hyperlink on a number on iphone, ipad?

Tags: html, ios, css

Does anyone know how I can stop only some sets of numbers from being linked eg numéros - but also let the iphone link the real phone numbers?

```
<h2>Table</h2>
<table class="table table-sm table-striped table-hover">
<caption class="sr-only">Résultat(s) de recherche</caption>
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">Nom</th>
   <th scope="col">Numéro</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr tabindex="0" role="button" onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'">
    <td>123 Plomberie</td>
    <td class="no_underline">25458-5172-53</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This solution worked for all type of number, but how let the iphone link the real phone numbers : https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4459/keep-iphone-browser-from-turning-numbers-into-links

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but temporary workaround, its worked for all number. Add this in header of html

```
 <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">
```